# expires max on Nginx

Tags: nginx, header, http-headers

I have a few questions about this directive:

- Is this what tells browser how often it should retrieve the file?
- What's the recommended setting hours/days/max for this on site css/image files?
- If I set this value to max, but then update some of the files on server, will user browsers not get the new files until they expire?

Answer (score 21):

`expires max;` sets browser cache expiration time in far future (2030 year). So, you should use it with caution. You will not be able to say to client, that file was changed. But, you would be able to rename file or to add some query to file name (e.g. "/style/main.css?v=2").

Always exclude location "favicon.ico" from `expires max`. This location is hardcoded in most browsers, so you won't be able to rename or add version to this file. Set expires for favicon to 1-2 month.

Comment: great suggestion for favicon.ico